# Fatal error: Call to undefined function load_theme_textdomain()

Tags: wordpress

I do not know if I can ask word press templated questions here. I was trying to add a line to functions.php in order to display images in RSS feeds. However, I missed to add a "/ "at the end  of my comment line and my website crashed.

I am getting this error: 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function load_theme_textdomain() in /home/content/31/6570531/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 33

the 33 line of functions.php has this line of code:
    load_theme_textdomain( 'btp_theme', get_template_directory().'/languages' );

is there anyone who knows what should I do? I reupload template files but still getting the same error.

this is the part of error I think

/* Initialize translation mechanism */
load_theme_textdomain( 'btp_theme', get_template_directory().'/languages' );

$locale  = get_locale();
$locale_file = TEMPLATEPATH . "/languages/$locale.php";
if ( is_readable($locale_file) )
    require_once($locale_file);

/* EnableWP Auto Feed Links */
add_theme_support('automatic-feed-links');

/* Enable post thumbnails support */
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

/* Enable custom backgrounds support */
add_custom_background();

if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) $content_width = 593;

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem and want to share it with you.

You should download a fresh copy of WordPress. Than delete

wp-config.php

and

wp-content directory

from your wordpress copy on your harddrive. These are vital steps in order you to not loose your settings and content.

Than upload the Wordpress files via FTP to your server.